# Angular 12:set and get value from a textbox in a record inside grid

Tags: javascript, angular

As title.
Let me use an example to explain what I want.  Assume that I am a teacher and have a set of student exam scores like this:

```
[
{"name":"John","score":88},
{"name":"Andy","score":80},
{"name":"Mary","score":93},
{"name":"Sandra","score":76},
{"name":"Thomas","score":55},
{"name":"Peter","score":69}
]
```

I want to display it inside a grid with score field is shown in an input area that I can edit to change student's score.  And I need to get the changed score of a student.  I can make my page as this:

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Name</th>
                          <th scope="col">Score</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let stu of students">
                            <td>{{stu.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{stu.score}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Then I didn't know how to make the score can be edited and how to get the edited value from a certain record.  Could someone guide me a way to get it?  I've searched use key word "angular set and get input inside grid" but find some didn't match what I needed and some uses older Angular.js and may not suitable for my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like this
ngModel will automatically update students;

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Name</th>
                          <th scope="col">Score</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let stu of students">
                            <td><input [(ngModel)]="stu.name"></input></td>
                            <td><input [(ngModel)]="stu.score"></input>}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```